# Tool to design circuits having raspberry pi

Tags: design

I have used some motors and IR proximity sensors in my raspberry pi project. 
I need to create a schematics/blueprint of my circuit showing RPi GPIO pins connection with the components. Like PSpice ,QUCS or EasyEDA but having raspberry pi , motors and IR sensors as components in their design library.

I need not to simulate or run it , just need to create a circuit.

Comment: For low budget, complexity what about [fritzing](http://fritzing.org/learning/tutorials/designing-pcb/) Pictures of  [raspberry pi 3 parts](https://www.google.de/search?q=fritzing+parts+raspberry+pi&num=40&newwindow=1&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIq-Hhk-jVAhWLbZoKHd0HCLkQ_AUICygC&biw=1441&bih=883) and [fritzing fab](https://aisler.net/fritzing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Fritzing](http://fritzing.org/home/) is what you think you need.

But even if Fritzing has a lot of ready to use components you quickly will need to create your own!
So, don't select a software only because it responds to your today's needs.

Comment: Fritzing is what I wanted.  I am loving it. Thanks.

Comment: "Friends don't let friends use Fritzing": https://hackaday.com/2016/10/11/creating-a-pcb-in-everything-friends-dont-let-friends-use-fritzing/

Answer (score 3):

I believe Eagle might be what you are looking for, but just looked at the Wiki page, and seen that it was bought by Autodesk last year - but they still supply a student free copy: https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/overview

Farnell owned it before and I believe developed libraries for the RPi, but you will need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Update to mid-2019:

Fritzing is still the answer. It is free, pretty open and bug free (for Mac OS at least) and there are a number of good components that you might be using in your breadboard already. It is a bit biased towards Arduino in terms of available and recent components; however, compared to subscription/licensed products, it works quite well - unless this is what you do - week after week. For the occasional use, I find it perfect. I have not tried CircuitMaker, which is a newer entrant into the "free" world.

Comment: "Friends don't let friends use Fritzing." This changed my life: https://hackaday.com/2016/10/11/creating-a-pcb-in-everything-friends-dont-let-friends-use-fritzing/

Comment: If you're actually going to create a PCB, I agree. If you're not, it is an easy way to document/think through a small idea.